# Как вывести 3 лучшие результата из excel файла на странице wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, файлы, excel, wordpress-плагины

Есть сайт на `wordpress` и есть `excel` таблица с рейтингом лидеров. 
Подскажите как можно вывести из файла на странице фамилии 3 победителей по результату максимального значения в колонке? 
Есть ли для этого готовые плагины или функционал?

Comment: Задача специфична, только самому писать.

Comment: Я бы сделал так. Подключил бы библиотеку PHPExcel и настроил область для получения данных таблицы, далее через обычный цикл нашел бы 3 лучших результата. Теперь эти данные я бы куда-нибудь сохранил, чтобы не делать лишние обращения. И поставил бы проверку на дату последнего изменения файла.